# Safari printing multicolumn page differently from Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, printing, safari

I have a button which should print information taken from the page in two columns. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox and prints as expected, however I seem to have an issue when trying to do it in Safari.

First off, the multi-column aspect wont work. They're defined like this:

```
.modal-body
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
```

I've tried looking it up, and have found no relevant results for Safari. I've found a site which led me to this workaround:

```
.modal-body
  > *
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
```

It sort of worked, but it led to another problem, which is that it fixed the columns by filling it our horizontally first instead of vertically (i.e. First Name should be displayed first, followed by Last Name below on the same column. However this workaround puts the Last Name at the top of the second column, which I don't want)

My next problem is that some of the elements won't appear in the previews when I use Safari. Like I've stated earlier, there's an element which displays the "First Name:" and another which displays the actual name. It shows both properly in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari I usually only get the actual value without the "____:".

I've found that after waiting for like 5 minutes and trying to print it again, the values appear on the print preview again, but closing it and trying it again will make them disappear.

I'm not really sure where this problem stems from, but I think this part of the code is what displays those items

```
.item.form-group
  width 80mm !important
  page-break-inside avoid !important
  margin 0
  margin-right 10mm
  padding 0
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Hey there! I'm not really sure how to explain my question in better detail, but I tried my best. Thanks for the advice though!